# How to know why an x-ray image is wrongly predicted by the sequential model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I used a sequential model to predict X-ray images. Some images have been incorrectly predicted. Now, I want to know why those images are predicted wrong, how should I do?

[These are the images that are wrongly predicted.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LiZHh.png)

Comment: yo should see what is model is actually leaning and based on what features of images, it is classifying the images.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.